# Jagged Array vs Array of Array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

How do you think what can be difference between them?

```
new object[][] { new object[] { "1" }, new object[] { "2" }, new object[] { "3" } }

new object[] { new object[] { "1" }, new object[] { "2" }, new object[] { "3" } }
```

They only difference I see is overloaded params of methods.

```
static void Arr(object[][] oa)

static void Arr(object[] oa)
```

Maybe effeciency of memory?

Comment: Jagged Array is a array of arrays

Comment: Are you asking which one is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is type-safe; the second one isn't.

Both of your arrays are exactly the same, except that the second array is typed as containing `object`s, whereas the first one must contain `object[]`s (arrays).  Therefore, you could write

```
new object[] { DateTime.Now, new object[] { "1" }, new object[] { "2" }, ... }
```

Whereas you cannot write

```
new object[][] { DateTime.Now, new object[] { "1" }, new object[] { "2" }, ... }
```

...because `DateTime.Now` is not an `object[]`.

In practice, you should try to use the most restrictive type possible to prevent you from making mistakes.
In your case, you should use a `string[][]` to make sure you can't put `DateTime.Now` in an inner array.

Comment: I think you mean, the first is statically typed while the second is not. Both are type-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the second example you can have elements of type `object` in the array, while in the first you can have `object[]` elements.